# how to make visible a div which is initially hidden by clicking on button using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want that my hidden div will be visible continuously after clicking the button.

This is my js code:

```
document.getElementById("share").onclick=function show(){
    document.getElementById("taskdiv2").style.visibility='visible';   
};
```

This is my html code:

```
<a id="share" onclick="show()" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default"  href="">Share</a>

<div id="taskdiv2"  style="visibility:hidden" class="row">
    hiiiii !this is vivek.
</div>
```

Comment: Change your herf to : `href="#"`, that way it won't refresh the page.

Answer (score 1):

- Remove `inline` `onclick` attribute as you have registered event using `JavaScript`
- Add `event.preventDefault()` as default behavior of `<a>` elements is to navigate.

```js
document.getElementById("share").onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.getElementById("taskdiv2").style.visibility = 'visible';
};
```

```html
<a id="share" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default" href="">Share</a>

<div id="taskdiv2" style="visibility:hidden" class="row">
  hiiiii !this is vivek.
</div>
```

---

**If you are expecting `toggle` of visibility,**

Use [**`Element.classList.toggle`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#Methods)

```js
document.getElementById("share").onclick = function show() {
  document.getElementById("taskdiv2").classList.toggle('show');
};
```

```css
.show {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="taskdiv2">Content Goes Here!!!</div>
<button id="share">Toggle</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used an anchor tag, so it tries to go to a link unless you prevent default:

```
document.getElementById("share").onclick=function show(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   document.getElementById("taskdiv2").style.visibility='visible';
};
```

Alternatively changing your html anchor to a button will also do the trick, in which case above change is not required:

```
<button id="share" onclick="show()" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-default"  href="">Share</button>
```

It's best to do this using classes as mentioned in above answer by Rayon, if you are going for a better standard of coding. Though based on your requirement I would just add the class to your element, rather than toggle.

Comment: _"will be visible continuously after clicking the button"_ made me use `toggle`

Comment: @Rayon Doesn't "visible continuously" mean it will stay visible forever?

Comment: I think he meant just stays visible and doesnt hide anymore, toggle switches between show and hide right?

Answer (score -1):

```js
function becomevisible() {
  document.getElementById("div").style.opacity="1";
  }
```

```css
div {
  background:red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div id="div">Test</div>
<button onclick="becomevisible()">See the div!</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
try this one out :

document.getElementById("share").onclick = function show() {
  document.getElementById("taskdiv2").classList.toggle('show');
};
.show {
  visibility: hidden;
}
<div id="taskdiv2">Content Goes Here!!!</div>
<button id="share">Toggle</button>
```